# Clever feed results | MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm running a social network site and I'm looking for new and more clever ways to output posts.

Database Table example:

```
id [INT]
message [LONGTEXT] Default NULL
attachment [VARCHAR] Default NULL
member_id [INT]
likes [INT] default 0
date [DATE]
etc
```

I understand this is a very vague example, but I think it's sufficient enough to ask this question.

How would I write a MySQL query to output exactly 3 posts with attachments only (no message), followed by one posts with a message only (no attachment), followed by 6 posts with the highest number of "likes", then repeat this process until LIMIT is reached?

I understand I might be asking for a lot, so any variation to this would be highly appreciated. Also, any links to relative content would be a lot of help too. Thank you very much.

Comment: Nothing to be honest. I've spent days searching and Googling for solutions but I can't find anything.

Comment: Isn't it easier to run 3 queries in a loop in the site's scripting language?

Comment: @Kenney True, but I want to limit the number of queries, hopefully try to do it all in one query

Comment: I believe you could use [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a stupid way to do it:

Like @Kenney have suggested you can use union to merge the 3 sets. Before applying union, we need to order each set in the way we want, and add a row_id to each row in each set. After applying union, we can order the result by

- `floor(row_id/divisor)`, so first 3 items in first set, first 1 item in second set, and first 6 items in third set evaluate to 0. next 3 items in first set, next 1 item in second set, and next 6 items in third set evaluate to 1. and so on.
- `type_id`, so first set appear before second set before third set

I'm pretty sure this is inefficient.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    (SELECT *, @i:=@i+1 row_id, 1 type_id, 3 divisor
    FROM mytable a
    JOIN (SELECT @i := 0) b
    WHERE attachment IS NOT NULL AND message IS NULL)
    UNION ALL 
    (SELECT *, @j:=@j+1 row_id, 2 type_id, 1 divisor
    FROM mytable a
    JOIN (SELECT @j := 0) b
    WHERE attachment IS NULL AND message IS NOT NULL)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT *, @k:=@k+1 row_id, 3 type_id, 6 divisor
    FROM mytable a
    JOIN (SELECT @k := 0) b
    WHERE !((attachment IS NOT NULL AND message IS NULL) OR (attachment IS NULL AND message IS NOT NULL))
    ORDER BY likes DESC)) a
ORDER BY FLOOR(row_id/divisor), type_id;
```